# Q. Should I be able to push up shingles on edge of new roof?

Tags: roof

Just had my roof replaced with architectural shingles. Should I be concerned that I can push up the portion of the shingles over hanging the roof edge by about an inch?

Comment: Are you in a “high wind” zone?

Comment: @LeeSam 110 mph zone

Comment: If the shingles were literally just installed, the seal down strips probably haven't had time to fuse together yet. These rely on solar gain to fuse, and a roof done in the middle of the winter is going to take quite a bit longer to "set".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to GAF Roofing manufacturer’s installation guide, the shingles should overhang the rake between 1/4” and 3/4”.

Here’s their website that explains it better: https://www.gaf.com/en-us/document-library/documents/residentialroofing/shingles/glenwood/glenwood_shingles_application_instructions_english_spanish_french.pdf

Yes, you should be able to push the shingles up about 1”, but if they extend too far beyond the edge of the roof (especially in a high wind area like you live in) they’re more susceptible to blow off.

Also critical is the correct number of nails per shingle. In high wind areas, 6 nails are required.

GAF is a major Roofing manufacturer in the U.S., but I’d check with your shingle manufacturer’s instructions.

Comment: After waiting for some hot days I can confirm that the shingles are now much tighter.